# Excel VBA - Grouping rows by cell condition (bold or non bold)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I'm trying to create code in Excel which will select rows based on condition (bold or nonbold) in a range and group them together using the group function in Excel.

The following code is where I've got to which selects all rows which are 0. Unfortunately, I cannot use the group function when multiple rows are selected that are not nonbold.

```
    Sub SelectGroupRows0()

Dim c As Range
Dim rng0 As Range
Dim block As Range

Set block = Range("B4:B23")

For Each c In block
    If c = 0 Then
        If rng0 Is Nothing Then Set rng0 = c.EntireRow
        Set rng0 = Union(rng0, c.EntireRow)

    Else: End If
Next c

rng0.Select
Selection.Rows.Group
```

for example structure is like;

- bold cell

  - non bold cell (will be grouped 1)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 1)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 1)
- bold cell (will stop grouping)

  - non bold cell (will be grouped 2)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 2)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 2)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 2)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 2)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 2)
- bold cell (will stop grouping)

  - non bold cell (will be grouped 3)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 3)
  - non bold cell (will be grouped 3)

i've tried to make something but.. if you can help me a little or trick.
will be grateful :)

thanks.